Probability of Successful Request Among Competing Actions
Consider a scenario with $N$ players, each independently submitting a request for action A, including ourselves as one of the players, and simultaneously, $M$ other players submitting requests for action B.
All requests are processed by a mediator in a random order.
Our request for action A will be successful if and only if it is processed before all other $N - 1$ requests for action A and also before at least one of the $M$ requests for action B.
What is the probability that our request for action A is successful?
My attempt: Consider the probability that our request for action A is processed before all other requests for action A: this probability is $\frac{1}{N}$.
Next, the probability that our request for action A is processed before at least one of the requests for action B is $1 - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^M$.
Therefore, the probability of success, where both conditions are met, is the product of these two probabilities:
$$
\frac{1}{N} \cdot \left( 1 - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^M \right).
$$
Is my result correct? It seems to be inconsistent with empirical data I have, but I am not sure what my error is.

Why do you treat the $A$ and $B$ applications so differently?  Consider the $M$ requests for $B$ and add your request for $A$.  That's $M+1$ requests in total.  In that string, there is only one bad position for your request, namely the last.  Thus the probability of being in a good position in that string is $\frac {M}{M+1}$.

To see that your second factor is wrong, consider the case $M=2$.  Then there are three relevant requests (those two and yours).  There are $6$ possible orders for these, each equally probable, the bad ones are the two in which you are last.  Thus the desired probability is $\frac 46=\frac 23$

While it is true that the probability that one given event precedes another is $\frac 12$, these are not independent events.  For instance, consider the case of three requests, $X,Y,Z$.  The probability that $Z$ is last is $\frac 13$, not $\left(\frac 12\right)^2=\frac 14$ as independence would have it.
Another approach:  Ignoring the individuals behind the requests, there are $\binom {M+N}M$ equally probable ways to order the requests.  As the $A's$ can be ordered in $N!$ ways, and the $B's$ in $M's$ ways. there are $M!\times N!\times \binom {N+M}M$ possible orderings.
How many of these are good?  Well, we need the first $A$ to be the right one.  the rest of the $A's$ can be in any order, so that gives a factor of  $(N-1)!$.  Then we must avoid the case in which all the $B's$ come before a single $A$ is received, there are $M!\times (N-1)!$ such cases.  Thus the answer is $$P(N,M)=\frac {(N-1)!\times M!\times \binom {N+M}M-M!\times (N-1)!}{N!\times M!\times \binom {N+M}{M}}$$
That simplifies to $P(N,M)=\boxed {\frac 1N-\frac 1{N\binom {N+M}M}}$.
Note:  This assumes that $M>0$.  If $M=0$ then we simply drop the second term.
Sanity checks:

$P(1,1)=\frac 12$ clearly, as you need your request to come in first, and the formula confirms this.

$P(1, M)=\frac M{M+1}$ since the only bad case is the one in which you are last.  The formula gives $P(1, M)=1-\frac 1{M+1}$ as desired.

Large $N$.  For a fixed $M$, as $N$ gets large the answer must approach $\frac 1N$ as there is effectively no chance that all the $M's$ come first.  The formula confirms this.

$P(2,1)$.  Lets lable the requests $A_1, A_2, B$ where yours is $A_1$.  Now there are $6$ possible orders of which exactly $2$ are good so the answer is $\frac 13$, confirmed by the formula.



Thank you for the detailed answer. I understand everything except the equation after "Thus the answer is...". Could you please elaborate on why that's what we obtain based on your earlier points in that paragraph?

The numerator is the number of good cases, the denominator is the number of total cases.

Quick way to thin of it, ignore the condition on $B$, then the answer is just $\frac 1N$ like you said.  To impose the condition on $B$ we have to subtract the cases in which all the $B's$ come first, but that's just one pattern out of the total, and that's the meaning of the $\frac 1{\binom {N+M}N}$ term.

Note:  I made an off-by-one error, now corrected.  We first look at the good cases ignoring the condition on $B$ requests.  There are $M!\times N!\times \binom {N+M}N$ of those as stated.  Now, from those we subtract the cases in which all the $B$ requests came first.  There are $M!\times (N-1)!$ of those, since we still require that your request came first.
